# Crawl table data from 2 drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have this website: https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US

[image]

This website has 2 dropdown menu: the `Category` and `SubCategory`. After choosing the `Category` and `SubCategory`, it will display a table, different `Category` and `SubCategory` will display a different table. How can I crawl this table for each `Category` and `SubCategory`.

This is what I try so far:

```
url = 'https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

content = soup.find("select",{"name":"ddlNatureId"})
options = content.find_all("option")
options1 = [y.text for y in options]
options1
```

The output:

```
['',
 'ADVOCATE OFFICES',
 'AGENCIES',
 'AGRICULTURE',
 'AGRICULTURE, LIVESTOCK AND FISHERIES ACTIVITIES',
 'ANIMAL HUSBANDRY',
 'ANIMAL SHELTERING SERVICES',
 'ART GALLERY',
 'AUDITING OFFICES',
 'BAKERIES AND SWEETS',
...
]
```

**Update:**

This is what I got so far. I found that using `Selenium` to select the value of the dropdown list. This is my code:

Some libraries:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

Set up `webdriver`:

```
url = 'https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US'
chrome_driver_path = 'D:\\work\\crawl data\\selenium_project\\chromedriver.exe'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)
```

Load the website and scrape data code:

```
with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # retrive url in headless browser
    driver.get(url)

    # find select box
    search = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlNatureId"))
    search.select_by_value('ADVOCATE OFFICES')

    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

    price=soup.find("select",{"name":"ddlSubCategId"})
    options = price.find_all("option")
    options1 = [y.text for y in options]

    driver.close()

print(options1)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Expected output (It should be the list of `SubCategory` which `Category` is  `'ADVOCATE OFFICES'`):

```
['',
'Advertising Agent',
'Advocate Offices',
'Agricultural Equipment And Tools Rental',
'Air Transport',
'Agents',
...
]
```

My problem right now is I cannot get the data of `SubCategory` when I select the `Category`. How can I solve this problem?